# Simple Java regex matcher not working

Tags: java, regex

Code :

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class eq {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        String str1 = "some=String&Here&modelId=324";
        Pattern rex = Pattern.compile(".*modelId=([0-9]+).*");
        Matcher m = rex.matcher(str1);
        System.out.println("id = " + m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to call [`find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) on the `Matcher` before you can call `group()` and related functions that queries about the matched text or manipulate it (`start()`, `end()`, `appendReplacement(StringBuffer sb, String replacement)`, etc.).

So in your case:

```
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("id = " + m.group(1));
}
```

This will find the *first* match (if any) and extract the first capturing group matched by the regex. Change `if` to `while` loop if you want to find all matches in the input string.

Answer (score 4):

You must add this line before calling `group()`:

```
m.find();
```

This moves the pointer to the start of the next match, if any - the method returns true if a match is found.

Usually, this is how you use it:

```
if (m.find()) {
    // access groups found. 
}
```